# Is it normal for my cat to become extremely affectionate while in heat?

Tags: cats, behavior

Among plentiful behaviors exhibited by my cat only when in heat, one is getting extremely affectionate.

My cat will constantly for 24 hours go on prodding me to pet her. Wherever I am she would come to me and start rubbing her head against me. Then she would start rolling over me. She would purr loudly. She would start licking me. She won't allow me to even sleep constantly moving by the side of my belly and rubbing herself against it.

But surprisingly, like all other not so normal behavior, she stops this once the heat wears off. Then she would only respond in an affectionate tone when I call her name and prod me only for food.

I am totally confused by her sudden change in personality whenever heat kicks in. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Is this normal?

Yes this is part of the process, it's the main behavior people will see that makes them realize their cat is in heat. Mostly because their cat keeps them up all night.

### How to help?

Cats are induced ovulators, meaning they need to mate to ovulate (stop the heat cycle). You can use a Q-tip to induce ovulation if you find that she keeps you up all night or can't handle the constant meowing. If it's your first time doing it I would get one of the veterinary staff to show you so it can be done appropriately.

Comment: The Q-tip method is extremely bad. I have first hand experience. Unlike many other mammals cats do not have menstruation. But after Q-tip ovulation takes place. As she is unable to mate and fertilize her eggs, the eggs remain in her uterus. More often than not, it results in development of cyst in uterus.